# JQuery drops first element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm creating a dynamic tabs using JQuery. But it always drops first element (In this case "li" is missing). Can anyone help to identify the problem.

Javascript code:-

```
var cars = ["Volvo", "BMW"];
    for (var key in cars) {
        var currAcc = cars[key];
        var curElement = '<li class="hover">';
        curElement += '<a href="#" id="currStudent">';
        curElement += '<i class="menu-icon fa fa-user"></i>';
        curElement += '<span class="menu-text">' + currAcc + '</span>';
        curElement += '</a>';
        curElement += '<b class="arrow"></b>';
        curElement += '</li>';
        console.log('curElement: ' + curElement);
        console.log('curElementHTML: ' + $(curElement).html());
    }
```

Outcome on dev tools (scratch):

curElement: `<li class="hover"><a href="#" id="currStudent"><i class="menu-icon fa fa-user"></i><span class="menu-text">Volvo</span></a><b class="arrow"></b></li>`

curElementHTML: `<a href="#" id="currStudent"><i class="menu-icon fa fa-user"></i><span class="menu-text">Volvo</span></a><b class="arrow"></b>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `html` function returns the [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) of the element.

What you seem to want is the [`outerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML).

Starting from a jQuery element ,you may use

```
$yourJQueryElement[0].outerHTML
```

Here you may simply do

```
console.log('curElementHTML: ' + curElement.outerHTML);
```